# "package android.support.v7.app does not exist" error in androidStudio

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx, appcompatactivity

i am just starting with android development using androidStudio 
i am following udacity tutorial where they asked us to copy paste some code and run it 
i am unable to run the cod after pasting 
i think the major problem is while importing

`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

i have checked internet for solution to this problem including stackoverflow 
but it seems that it is different for each case 
i have tried to import 
`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppcompatActivity;`
instead of 
`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`
but it didn't hepled
i am using androidStudio version 3.4

Main activity:

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

/**
 * IMPORTANT: Make sure you are using the correct package name.
 * This example uses the package name:
 * package com.example.android.justjava
 * If you get an error when copying this code into Android studio, update it to match teh package name found
 * in the project's AndroidManifest.xml file.
 **/


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

module.App(build gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

```
error: cannot find symbol class AppcompatActivity   
error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatActivity   
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype  
error: cannot find symbol variable super    
error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)    
error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
```

Comment: Post your layout file here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using  [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) libraries.

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Then you **can't use** the import of **support libraries** classes.

It is the [right class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity):

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: Hi @MueezKhan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This saved me from a very frustrating day at work yesterday, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

notice lack of uppercase in your App**C**ompat import:

`import 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppcompatActivity'`

instead of App**C**ompatActivity

Java/Android is case sensitive. `android.support.v7` is kind of deprecated, AndroidX is replacing it

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since androidx library somewhere in june 2019... To solve this simple problem, make sure you do the following;

1. go to your gradle.properties file and enable androidx as you can see in my example picture below
   [step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zELO7.png)
2. Now go to the top menu of your android studio, click on **Refactor** and click on **"Migrate to androidx"**
3. Android studio automatically will do all the importation syntax corrections of androidx in your gradle

Answer (score 0):

update build gradle, then change import line from

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

to

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

and check your package name from AndroidManifest.xml