# error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist Problem

Tags: java, android

I keep getting such an error, what's wrong? and Have another problem?
This gives the first three red-shaped bugs!

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

;

I am new to android development, and I have been using the command line tools to create an android project. I followed all the instructions given in the tutorial at android developers. However, they are focused more on IDE users.

```
findbugs {
    sourceSets = []
    ignoreFailures = false
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "video.compress.optimizasyon"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 20
        versionName "0.20"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable "GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        disable "MissingTranslation"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // ACRA depends on Java 8
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}    
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
        implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
        implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
        implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '24.1-jre'
        implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.2.1'
        implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.18'
        implementation group: 'org.javatuples', name: 'javatuples', version: '1.2'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
        implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.11'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    }
```

Comment: You are using the androidx libraries. Remove the support packages and libraries (as `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'`) and add the [right imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546020/package-android-support-v7-app-does-not-exist-error-in-androidstudio/57546037#57546037).

Comment: i did not solved, what is coreect    implementation list plaease help me?

Comment: Posted in the answer all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using androidx libraries.

**Remove** this dependency, since you are using the Material Components library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

Then change these classes (code and layout):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

to

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.IdRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
//import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Here the full [class mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).